# What is mean name after variable name in t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the next query:

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
SET @startdate = ''1/1/1990''
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT @startdate DateVal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateVal + 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE DateVal + 1 <= @enddate
    )
```

Сan you please explain what it means instruction:

```
@startdate DateVal
```

Is a variable called `startdate` assigned a different name? But why?

Comment: that is call `column alias`. Please do refer to documentation for further details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would write this as:

```
@startdate as DateVal
```

The two are equivalent, but this is clearer in intent (and less likely to cause problems).

In any case, `@startdate` is not a valid column name in a table -- or CTE.  So, you want to give it a valid name.  That is what this is doing.

If you don't give it a name, you will get an error, as illustrated [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d173f1e026ada0b4f0293edaac5469ae).

You should also use standard date formats, so I would suggest:

```
SET @startdate = '1990-01-01';  -- ISO standard format but could be affected by internationalization formats
```

or:

```
SET @startdate = '19900101';    -- SQL Server standard format.  Unambiguous.
```